# Feature engineering of rolling windows with apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have been able to read in the following data representing customer transactions as csv with Beam (Python SDK).

```
timestamp,customer_id,amount
2018-02-08 12:04:36.899422,1,45.92615814813004
2019-04-05 07:40:17.873746,1,47.360044568200514
2019-07-27 04:37:48.060949,1,23.325754816230106
2017-05-18 15:46:41.654809,2,25.47369262400646
2018-08-08 03:59:05.791552,2,34.859367944028875
2019-01-02 02:44:35.208450,2,5.2753275435507705
2020-03-06 09:45:29.866731,2,35.656304542140404
2020-05-28 20:19:08.593375,2,23.23715711587539
```

The csv is being read in as follows:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.textio import ReadFromText

import datetime

class Split(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        timestamp, customer_id, amount = element.split(",")

        return [{
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'customer': int(customer_id),
            'amount': float(amount)
        }]


options = PipelineOptions()
    
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:

    rows = (
        p |
        ReadFromText('../data/sample_trxns.csv', skip_header_lines=1) |
        beam.ParDo(Split())
    )
    

    class UnixTime(beam.DoFn):
    
        def process(self, element):
            """
            Returns a list of tuples containing customer and amount
            """
            
            unix_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                element['timestamp'],
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
                ).timestamp()
  
                            
            return [{
                'timestamp': unix_time,
                'customer': element['customer'],
                'amount': element['amount']
            }]
             
    class AddTimestampDoFn(beam.DoFn):
      def process(self, element):
        unix_timestamp = element['timestamp']
        # Wrap and emit the current entry and new timestamp in a
        # TimestampedValue.
        yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, unix_timestamp)
   
    
    timed_rows = (
        rows |
        beam.ParDo(UnixTime()) |
        beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())
        )
```

However with Beam I have been unable to derive rolling window features such as for 'customer mean transaction value over last 1000 days', and equivalent rolling window features for min, max and sum (excluding the current row in each calculation). This demonstrates the desired values of the feature calculating with the pandas.Series.rolling function and printing the resulting pandas dataframe:

```py
                            customer_id     amount  mean_trxn_amount_last_1000_days
timestamp                                                                          
2018-02-08 12:04:36.899422            1  45.926158                              NaN
2019-04-05 07:40:17.873746            1  47.360045                        45.926158
2019-07-27 04:37:48.060949            1  23.325755                        46.643101
2017-05-18 15:46:41.654809            2  25.473693                              NaN
2018-08-08 03:59:05.791552            2  34.859368                        25.473693
2019-01-02 02:44:35.208450            2   5.275328                        30.166530
2020-03-06 09:45:29.866731            2  35.656305                        20.067348
2020-05-28 20:19:08.593375            2  23.237157                        25.263667
```

I have not found any documentation for similar functionality in Beam - is such functionality available? If not, am I misunderstanding the intended scope of what Beam is meant to provide, or is this sort of functionality likely to be available in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) as you have extracted the timestamps in your sample code.

Fixed windows:
*"The simplest form of windowing is using fixed time windows: given a timestamped PCollection which might be continuously updating, each window might capture (for example) all elements with timestamps that fall into a 30 second interval."*

Sliding windows:
*"A sliding time window also represents time intervals in the data stream; however, sliding time windows can overlap. For example, each window might capture 60 seconds worth of data, but a new window starts every 30 seconds. The frequency with which sliding windows begin is called the period. Therefore, our example would have a window duration of 60 seconds and a period of 30 seconds."*

Apply the window then make use of either the inbuilt functions for Min/Max/Sum etc... or create your own combiner.